# Chrome vs JS: Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token )

Tags: javascript, debugging, google-chrome, token, console.log

I have noticed that the assignment "javascript:void()" within the link:

```
<a href="javascript:void()" id="link_id">My link</a>
```

is caused an error in Chrome Dev console like this:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token )
```

But why? Is this code is incorrect? If it is correct how to avoid such an ugly issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `javascript:void(0)`

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/void

Answer (score 1):

You have to use with `0` like this

```
<a href="javascript:void(0)" id="link_id">My link</a>
```

For more information about this, please go through the excellent answers in [Which "href" value should I use for JavaScript links, "#" or "javascript:void(0)"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/134845/href-attribute-for-javascript-links-or-javascriptvoid0)